# Saving photo from camera to a directory in android app fails

Tags: android, camera, directory

I am working on android app which is suppose to take a photo and save it in some directory. 
I have tried the code in the android developers site (http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) and it works perfectly. 
I modified it a little and used some code in my app but it fails at making the pictures directory and i get the error at the Logcat:

09-10 01:32:44.081: D/CameraSample(1477): failed to create directory

here is my code:

```
public class TakePhoto{
public static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO = 1; 
private static AlbumStorageDirFactory mAlbumStorageDirFactory = null;
private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";
private static String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private static final String DEBUG_TAG= "PhotoIntent"; 
private static int counter = 0; 
/* private constructor */
private TakePhoto (){   }

public static File StorageDir(String dirName){
    File storageDir = null;
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG , counter++ + " GetAlbumName: " + dirName);
        storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(dirName);
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG , counter++ + " GetAlbumDir: " + storageDir);
        if (storageDir != null) {
            if (! storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                if (! storageDir.exists()){
                    Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.v(dirName, "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
    }

    return storageDir;
}

public static String saveInDir(String dirName){
    File storage =  StorageDir(dirName); 
    if (storage == null){
        storage = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); 
        if (!storage.mkdir())
            return null; 
    }
    File imageF;
    try {
        imageF = File.createTempFile(setUpPicName() , JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, storage);
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG , counter++ + " CreateImageFile: " + imageF.toString() + "  " + imageF.getAbsolutePath());
        mCurrentPhotoPath = imageF.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG , counter++ + " IOexception: " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
        mCurrentPhotoPath = null; 
    }
    return mCurrentPhotoPath; 
}

public static void setDirFactory(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG , counter++ + " foryoAlbumDirFactory: ");
        } else {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
        }
}
```

at the line:

```
 storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(dirName);
```

getAlbumStorageDir is called from FroyoAlbumDirFactory.java:

```
package beeah.ae.takephoto;
import java.io.File;

import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;

public final class FroyoAlbumDirFactory extends AlbumStorageDirFactory {

    @Override
    public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
        Log.d("FroyoFactory" , "Inside froyofactory");
        return new File(
          Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
          ), 
          albumName
        );
    }
}
```

P.S. when i debug storageDir content it gives me:

09-10 01:32:43.971: D/PhotoIntent(1477): 2 GetAlbumDir: /storage/sdcard/Pictures/myPictures

Comment: First of all you forget to check that media is mounted or not. See Ripal Tamboli's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saving picture to external storage, you need to check that card is mounted or not by writing below code. so it will stop your app from crashing in the middle.

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

if(isSDPresent)
{
  // continue with your picture saving code
}
else
{
 // show message to user
}
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: Thank you :D 
i think this was my problem

Answer (score 2):

Please post your logcat error here and also check that have you given permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your manifest.xml file.

Comment: thank you, i didn't put this permission.. but now i got other problems, sometimes the when i press the button the camera crashes at run time and other times it tells me there is no external storage mounted. what should i do?

Comment: can you place your entire code here as code of dealing with camera to take picture is missing here. Also post that logcat error. so it will help us to track exact problem. :)